# Se douter : L'effet renversant du pronom se

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie, verbes-pronominaux

Je connais les définitions de [**se douter**](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/se%20douter). Par ailleurs, quelques de ses [synonymes](http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/cgi-bin/trouvebis2?requete=se+douter&refer=%23&proc=0813_15916b) sont , par ordre décroissant de parenté : *soupçonner > imaginer > penser > deviner > pressentir > conjecturer > s'attendre > ...*

Au demeurant, je voudrais comprendre le rôle du pronom réflexif **se** dans la juxtaposition **se + douter** qui fait que **se douter** constitue un antonyme de *douter*. Pourquoi *douter* (tout seul) change-t-il radicalement de sens en présence du pronom ? De plus, comment se fait-il que « se douter bien » puisse signifier « être sûr » ???

Comment: Du même acabit: _sans doute_ exprime un doute.

Comment: @mouviciel C'est curieux, mais je comprends "sans doute" littéralement, comme "sans aucun doute", sans aucune crainte de se tromper : "c'est sans doute lui l'assassin" = "ça ne peut-être que lui" ?

Comment: @MarkThorin - Justement quand on veut exprimer qu'il n'y a pas de doute, on dit: _sans __aucun__ doute_. Le [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sans_doute) abonde dans ce sens, sans rejeter le sens étymologique.

Comment: @mouviciel Le Wiktionnaire donne "sans aucun doute" comme familier (? mais c'est utilisé dans des décisions juridiques) dans l'acception de "probablement", et comme synonyme de "assurément" ; je reste d'autant plus perplexe qu'un lien renvoie à l'anglais "arguable", présenté comme (quasi-)certitude, alors que cela signifie "contestable", "discutable", plus exactement à "arguably", qui veut dire "ça peut se discuter, on peut raisonnablement soutenir que". Il renvoie aussi à l'allemand, indiscutablement "sans nul doute" ; et aussi au finnois que ... sans doute je ne maîtrise pas parfaitement.

Comment: @mouviciel: Pourriez-vous expliciter cette locution adverbe ? http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/doute en va de même que ex-user2728: **sans doute** = Assurément, certes. Autrement dit, **sans doute** = nul doute ?

Comment: @LePressentiment - Outre le fait que le Littré commence à être daté, le sens numéro 5 indique bien _Sans doute que s'emploie aussi pour probablement_

Comment: @mouviciel: Merci beaucoup. Si je vous compris pleinement, vous affirmez que contre-intuitivement, sans doute ≠ 100% doute (c-à-d : < 100% doute) ?

Comment: @LePressentiment: 0% plutôt. Et ce n'est qu'un des sens. Le sens litéral existe aussi.

Answer (score 1):

*douter* : "Craindre, hésiter" qui donne *redouter* ; être dans l'incertitude de (la réalité d'un fait, la vérité d'une assertion)

 ...
*se douter* : considérer comme tout à fait probable (ce dont on n'a pas connaissance) -  (extraits du petit Robert)

Il y a les mouvements de *croire que* :

- je doute, je *ne crois pas* que cela soit vrai je n'en suis absolument pas certain,
- je me doute , *je crois* que cela est possible, c'est presque une certitude

Si je doute de la réalité à laquelle je suis confronté, je suis en position défensive car mes certitudes sont potentiellement mises à bas (mouvement centripète, l'objet *incertitude* m'est extérieur, et donc je n'ai pas tous les moyens de connaître ce qui s'approche de moi).

Si ma subjectivité a perçu quelque chose qu'elle prend pour valable (parfois pour la pure vérité), bien que je n'en ait pas une certitude absolue, je peux projeter qu'elle soit vraie (mouvement centrifuge, *l'incertitude* de mon intuition demande à être confronté à la réalité, à l'extérieur de moi).

Ainsi, selon le point de vue objectif ou subjectif, l'incertitude du doute change de sens.

Limité à ce  contexte, en pure logique, *je **doute** de la chose dont l'autre **se doute***, ou *l'incertitude de l'un fait la certitude de l'autre*.

Comment: Je ne suis pas entièrement d'accord, mais je clique en votre faveur, car : a) votre réponse est bonne ; b) c'est dommage qu'une excellente question reste parmi les "unanswered ones".

Answer (score 1):

Il faut remonter à l'étymologie, *dubitare*, qui signifie non seulement douter au sens intellectuel, mais être mal assuré, voire, pour une chose, être en équilibre précaire.

Jusqu'au début de l'époque classique, douter signifiait aussi craindre, sens qui n'apparaît plus que dans redouter (le "re", complètement superflu, est peut-être d'influence normande).

"Je me doute que" signifiait donc "j'ai bien peur d'être de mauvais jugement", avant de s'affaiblir jusqu'à signifier "je n'en suis pas sûr, mais c'est bien possible", et enfin "je me le disais bien".

"S'apercevoir" a eu une évolution similaire, mais exactement opposée : initialement "je me vois vaguement", jusqu'à "enfin je vois les choses clairement".

Comment: On peut connaître les sources sur lesquelles tu t'appuies ?

Comment: J'ai vérifié après, dans le Gaffiot, le dictionnaire étymologique Larousse, et le Littré qui cite la Chanson de Roland, Villehardouin, Commines, Calvin ... sans aucun doute dans le sens de "crainte". Et dans le "Etymological Dictionary" d'Oxford ; cela peut paraître bizarre, mais l'anglais a reçu les deux tiers de son vocabulaire du français, en gardant généralement bien mieux les sens et prononciation (d'où l'explication de nombreuses difficultés d'inter-compréhension).